# Do private functions use more or less computer resources than public ones?

Tags: java, private, public

Computer resources being RAM, possessing power, and disk space. I am just curious, even though it is more or less by a tiny itty-bitty amount.

Comment: What is the logic behind your suspicion that one would be any different than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could, in theory, be a *hair* faster in some cases. In practice, they're equally fast.

Non-static, non-public methods are invoked using the `invokevirtual` bytecode op. This opcode requires the JVM to dynamically look up the actual's method resolution: if you have a call that's statically compiled to `AbstractList::contains`, should that resolve to `ArrayList::contains`, or `LinkedList::contains`, etc? What's more, the compiler can't just reuse the result of this compilation for next time; what if the next time that `myList.contains(val)` gets called, it's on a different implementation? So, the compiler has to do at least *some* amount of checking, roughly per-invocation, for non-private methods.

Private methods can't be overridden, and they're invoked using `invokespecial`. This opcode is used for various kind of method calls that you can resolve just once, and then never change: constructors, call to super methods, etc. For instance, if I'm in `ArrayList::add` and I call `super.add(value)` (which doesn't happen there, but let's pretend it did), then the compiler can know for sure that this refers to `AbstractList::add`, since a class's super class can't ever change.

So, in very rough terms, an `invokevirtual` call requires resolving the method and then invoking it, while an `invokespecial` call doesn't require resolving the method (after the first time it's called -- you have to resolve everything at least once!).

This is covered in the [JVM spec, section 5.4.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3):

> Resolution of the symbolic reference of one occurrence of an invokedynamic instruction *does not* imply that the same symbolic reference is considered resolved for any other invokedynamic instruction.
>
> For all other instructions above, resolution of the symbolic reference of one occurrence of an instruction *does* imply that the same symbolic reference is considered resolved for any other non-invokedynamic instruction.

(empahsis in original)

Okay, now for the "but you won't notice the difference" part. The JVM is heavily optimized for virtual calls. It can do things like detecting that a certain site always sees an `ArrayList` specifically, and so "staticify" the `List::add` call to actually be `ArrayList::add`. To do this, it needs to verify that the incoming object really is the expected `ArrayList`, but that's very cheap; and if some earlier method call has already done that work in this method, it doesn't need to happen again. This is called a monomorphic call site: even though the code is technically polymorphic, in practice the list only has one form.

The JVM optimizes monomorphic call sites, and even bimorphic call sites (for instance, the list is always an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`, never anything else). Once it sees three forms, it has to use a full polymorphic dispatch, which is slower. But then again, at that point you're comparing apples to oranges: a non-private, polymorphic call to a private call that's monomorphic *by definition*. It's more fair to compare the two kinds of monomorphic calls (virtual and private), and in that case you'll probably find that the difference is minuscule, if it's even detectible.

I just did [a quick JMH benchmark](https://gist.github.com/yshavit/e58acf243eda9b08285e) to compare (a) accessing a field directly, (b) accessing it via a public getter and (c) accessing it via a private getter. All three took the same amount of time. Of course, uber-micro benchmarks are very hard to get right, because the JIT can do such wonderful things with optimizations. Then again, that's kind of the *point*: The JIT does such wonderful things with optimizations that public and private methods are just as fast.

Answer (score 3):

> Do private functions use more or less computer resources than public ones?

No. The JVM uses the same resources regardless of the access modifier on individual fields or methods.

**But**, there is a far better reason to prefer `private` (or `protected`) beside resource utilization; namely [**encapsulation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29). Also, I highly recommend you read [The Developer Insight Series: Part 1 - Write Dumb Code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/devinsight-1-139780.html).

Answer (score 1):

> I am just curious, even though it is more or less by a tiny itty-bitty amount.

While it is good to be curious ... if you start taking this kind of thing into account when you are programming, then:

- you are liable to waste a lot of time looking for micro-optimizations that are not needed,
- your code is liable to be unmaintainable because you are sacrificing good design principles, and
- you even risk making your code *less* efficient<sup>*</sup> than it would be if you didn't optimize.

---

<sup>* - It it can go like this.  1) You spend a lot of time tweaking your code to run fast on your test platform.  2) When you run on the production platform, you find that the hardware gives you different performance characteristics. 3) You upgrade the Java installation, and the new JVM's JIT compiler optimizes your code differently, or it has a bunch of new optimizations that are *inhibited* by your tweaks. 4) When you run your code on real-world workloads, you discover that the assumption that were the basis for your tweaking are invalid.</sup>